# Detailed question on the proof of the classification of the group of order $pq$

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading James and Liebeck's book and have troubling understanding some part of the proof.

> Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime
> numbers with $p>q$. Then either $G$ is abelian, or $q$ divides $p-1$
> and $G\cong F_{p,q}$, where $F_{p,q}=<a, b:a^p=b^q=1,b^{-1}ab=a^u>$.

> Assume that $G$ is non-abelian. It follows that $q$ divides $p-1$ and
> $G$has a normal subgroup of $H$ or order $p$.

The text explains in the parenthesis that we can see this by Sylow's theorem. Can you please give me a bit of a detail for this? (not using semi-direct product)

> Both $H$ and $G/H$ are cyclic, since they have prime order. Suppose
> that $H=<a>$ and $G/H=<Hb>$; then $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$.

How do we set $G/H=<Hb>$? $Hb$ seems to be a right coset, and $G/H$ is a set of left cosets. I also don't understand why $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$ from the previous step. For the rest of the proof, I can follow.

> Now $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so $b^{-1}ab=a^u$ for some
> integer $u$. Further, $a=b^{-q}ab^q=a^{u^q}$ and so $u^q\equiv 1$ mod
> $p$.
> Thus the order of $u$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ divides $q$. If
> the order of $u$ were $1$ then we would have $b^{-1}ab=a$, and $G$ would
> be abelian. Therefore the order of $u$ is $q$. We have now established
> that $a^p=b^q=1,b^{-1}ab=a^u$, order of $u$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ is
> $q$. Hence $G\cong F_{p,q}$.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: The group $G/H$ has *prime order* so it is cyclic and $Hb$ is a generator of it. To show $a$ and $b$ generate $G$, pick $g\in G$ and think about what it means to say $Hg$ is a power of $Hb$.

Comment: At the very end of your post, you crucially misspelled “we  have now established” as “we have not established”.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't it be $bH$, not $Hb$? I really need to review group theory...

Comment: It’s a normal subgroup. Left and right cosets are the same so it doesn’t matter.

Comment: I personally would prefer to write $bH$ and $gH$, but *you* wrote $Hb$ in your post, so I followed that notation in my comment.

Comment: That was my original question, thanks